# Not able to find the bug in my multithreading program?

Tags: c, multithreading, mutex

I have implemented a simple multithreading program, where producer access the global variable and fills it, after that consumner prints it.

I have written the main like this

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<pthread.h>

void *prod(void);
void *cons(void);

unsigned int my_var = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mut = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

int main()
{
    pthread_t th1, th2;
    int status;

    status = pthread_create(&th1, NULL, (void*)prod, NULL);
    if(status)
    {
        printf("Error creating thread 1 : %d\n", status);
        exit(-1);
    }
    status = pthread_create(&th2, NULL, (void*)cons, NULL);
    if(status)
    {
         printf("Error creating thread 2 : %d\n", status);
         exit(-1);
    }

    pthread_join(th1, NULL);
    pthread_join(th2, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

my Producer function goes like this :

```
void *prod(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
        printf("Enter the value : ");
        scanf("%d", &my_var);
    }
}
```

Consumer function is :

```
void *cons(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("The value entered was %d\n", my_var);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    }
}
```

This program runs with exact output but pattern is different, like :

```
Enter the value : The value entered was 0
The value entered was 0
45
Enter the value : The value entered was 45
85
Enter the value : The value entered was 85
12
Enter the value : The value entered was 12
67
Enter the value : The value entered was 67
49
Enter the value : The value entered was 49
```

I am finding it difficult to rectify this logic as am new to threading concept.
Please help me out in resolving the issue.

My Expected output :

```
Enter the value : 45
The value entered is 45
.........................................
```

After some answer's and guidelines to use mutex_cond_var. I used them in the function like this :

```
void *prod(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        printf("Enter the value : ");
        scanf("%d", &my_var);
        pthread_cond_signal(&condition_var1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    }  
}

void *cons(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        pthread_cond_wait( &condition_var1, &mut );
        printf("The value entered was %d\n", my_var);
    }
}
```

Resulted output :

```
Enter the value : 78
Enter the value : The value entered was 78
86
Enter the value : 15
Enter the value : The value entered was 15
35
Enter the value : 86
Enter the value : The value entered was 86
12
Enter the value : 65
Enter the value : The value entered was 65
78
Enter the value : 65
Enter the value : The value entered was 65
12
Enter the value : 35
Enter the value : The value entered was 35
```

Please guide me in cleaning the code to get the expected output.

Comment: You need some mechanism to ensure `prod` gets executed first, then it can signal `cons` to print the value. ,, a `pthread_cond_t` conditional variable comes to mind. They are used for threads to signal each other when a specific condition is met (so `cons` can wait, `prod` can print then accept user input, after which it can signal `cons` to print the value then halt. After `cons` has printed it can signal `prod` to query the user again, etc). This is a good tutorial with examples: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: Just note: `prod` and `cons` functions take no arguments. But they [should](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) take `void *`. It seems there should be a warning

Comment: You shouldn't do what you are trying to do here. For a mutex it is mentioned in Pthread manual that  **If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked or a mutex which is unlocked, undefined behavior results.** If you needs to achieve producer consumer synchronization you should use `pthread_cond_wait()`, `pthread_cond_signal()` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use conditional variable for such cases.

https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#ConVarOverview

This way is more efficient for your task. So that consumer should wait for some cond variable. When producer will get new data, he will notify condition variable and consumer will wake up to do some job with that data.

The link above has pretty good explanation, but if you have questions, you are welcome

Comment: A semaphore is also a good alternative to a conditional variable.

Comment: @Martinn, I don't agree with you, especially for current question. Semaphore is a different synchronization object for different purposes. This one is good if you want to limit access to the some resources. For example you want allow 10 simultaneous threads to use some object.

Comment: Yes they can both be used. But in this example I prefer semaphores. The producer can increment the semaphore for every new data it creates, which will signal the consumer to do one unit of consuming. This better matches the producer/consumer design pattern. Also what happens when the producer produces faster than the consumer can consume? From your source: It is a logical error to call pthread_cond_signal() before calling pthread_cond_wait(), which may occur in that case.

Comment: I still don't agree with you. Sorry, but your example is also wrong.. If producer will produce faster than consumer can process, you still will lose data, because there is only one variable which stores payload in example above. In general, the producer should put data to the queue and signal cond var each time after inserting new value. Consumer wake ups and processes **ALL** values in queue. when queue is become empty, he just waits for new signal.

Answer (score 1):

Logically, Producer code might run multiple time before Consumer gets a chance to run. In such case you might miss some entered values. You will require 2 mutex. `mutex_full` and `mutex_empty`.

Initial values:  `mutex_full = NON_SIGNALED`   and   `mutex_empty = SIGNALED`

```
Producer()
{
Wait(mutex_empty);
//produce code
Signal(mutex_full);
}

Consumer()
{
Wait(mutex_full);
//consumer code
Signal(mutex_empty);
}
```